# Understanding Wright's proof of Landau's theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I'm reading Wright's *A simple proof of a theorem of Landau* in which the core argument is a proof by induction and I find myself stuck on a major point. I must be misunderstanding notation or something else, because what I understand is clearly wrong.

For the base case, he writes:

> But, for $k=1,$ (6) is equivalent to (2).

where (2) is a form of the Prime Number Theorem,
$$
\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\log p\sim x
$$

and (6) is
$$
\phi_k(x)=o\left\{(\log\log x)^{k-1}\right\}
$$

The relevant definitions:
$$
\begin{align}
\phi_k(x)&=\vartheta_k(x)-kx\Omega_{k-1}(x)\\
\vartheta_k(x)&=\sum_{p_1\cdots p_k\le x}\log(p_1\cdots p_k)\\
\Omega_0(x)&=1\\
\Omega_k(x)&=\sum_{p_1\cdots p_k\le x}\frac{1}{p_1\cdots p_k}\text{ for }k>0\\
\end{align}
$$
(where both $\vartheta_k$ and $\Omega_k$ count their sums with multiplicity) and so
$$
\phi_1(x)=\vartheta(x)-x
$$
but $|\psi(x)-x|\ne o(\sqrt x\log\log\log x)$ and $\psi(x)-\vartheta(x)=O(\sqrt x)$ hence $|\vartheta(x)-x|\ne o(\sqrt x\log\log\log x),$ and so $\phi_1(x)=\vartheta(x)-x\ne o(1)$ as required. (In any case it can't be $o(1)$ since there are arbitrarily long gaps in the primes.) What am I missing?

Comment: Reading the title I thought it was about Landau's Theorem on Dirichlet series. Perhaps you should give a more thorough background for what you exactly want.

Comment: @Timbuc: the proof seems to assume that theta(x) - x goes to 0, but it doesn't. What don't I get?

Comment: You didn't define $\Omega_k(x)$.

Comment: @EricNaslund: Yes, only $\Omega_0(x),$ because that's all that's used in the question. I can copy the full definition for you if you're interested.

Comment: @Charles: Well, yes, it's definitely relevant since this looks like a typo.

Comment: @EricNaslund: OK, I've edited to include it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a typo to me, and that equation $(6)$ should read $$\phi_k(x)=o\left(x\left(\log \log x\right)^{k-1}\right).$$

Knowing how the author defines $\Omega_{k-1}(x)$ for other values of $k$ would help confirm this.